# Mysqli - Using avg, sum, group by with two tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I know the basics when it comes to mysqli queries, but I'm having trouble with the following:

I have a large table called **caseStatistics** with the following columns:

**idSchool** (id for school), **timeReported** (unix timestamp), **timeRead** (unix timestamp), **timeSolved** (unix timestamp)

I have another large table called **school** with the following columns:

**idSchool** (id for school), **name** (name of school)

From these two tables, I want to output the name of the school, total cases, the avarage time it has taken for operators to respond to a case (after it was reported), and the avarage time on how long it has taken to solve the case (after it was reported). I also need the results to be grouped by the school name.

So it should output something like this:

**Name**: BlaBlaSchool

**Total cases**: 49

**Avarage respond time**: 2 hours

**Avarage solve time**: 16 hours

(For each school)

I don't need assistance with converting from unix to days, hours, minutes etc, only the mysqli query. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the functions into the column list in the select statement:

```
SELECT
  s.`name`,
  COUNT(*) AS totalCases,
  AVG(cs.`timeRead` - cs.`timeReported`) AS avgRespond,
  AVG(cs.`timeSolved` - cs.`timeReported`) AS avgSolved
FROM `caseStatistics` AS cs
LEFT JOIN `school` AS s ON s.`idSchool` = cs.`idSchool`
GROUP BY s.`name`
```

You can use the `HAVING` keyword to narrow results using the aggregate values (similar to `WHERE`). Also, make sure to check out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. The thing is that "name" is in another table called "school". So, I have to compare the idSchool from "caseStatistics" to idSchool in "school" to get the name. How will the query look then?

Comment: In that case, you will need a `JOIN`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Looking good here, except "SUM(*) AS totalCases" makes the query fail for some reason. If I remove it, the rest of the query works. Any clue what might cause that?

Comment: I solved it. Instead of SUM(), I used COUNT() to get amount of cases per school. Thank you @Siphon for your help! You're the man!